# Ask for confirmation in cancel and back envents with Genexus Ev3 for Smart Devices

Tags: android, genexus, genexus-sd

I need to ask the user for confirmation when he taps the back or the cancel buttons, but only when the transaction is in edit mode. ¿How can I ask the mode for the current transaction?

```
Event Back
    Composite       
        &Answer= interop.Confirm("If you do this, you could lost all unsaved data. ¿Do you want to continue?")
        if &Answer
            return
        EndIf
    EndComposite
Endevent
```

I'm working with Genexus Ev3 U2 for Android device.

Thanks

Comment: Right now I don't think you can do this, as the mode is not available to the developer. Sorry, we'll try to fix it.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, I'll be waiting for this feature then; from now the users should accept the confirmation always. thank you

Comment: This feature has been implemented as part of the next version (codenamed "Salto").

Comment: Thank you I'll be waiting for this release.

Answer (score 0):

u can try move a parameter moving Y when editing mode.

When u call the sdpanel input a variable &flag char(1) : "Y" when edit and "N" when note editing.

Event back
Composite
If &flag : "Y"
&hasConfirmed = interop.confirm ...........
 .
.
.
Endcomposite
Endevent